# Getting json response from variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, string

If doing `console.log(data)` from inside a function that get passed the result of an AJAX request outputs
[image]
in the google chrome developer tools, I am wondering how I can get to the value of result?
I think the entire response is being interpreted as a string? normally I would just use the `dataType` parameter, but I do not have control over this AJAX request.

Comment: How is the JSON fetched?

Comment: It's part of the [PLupload library](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload) so however that fetches it, I assume it's just a jQuery ajax request. this is the event binding for `FileUploaded` aka ` uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, data) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.response` property contains an object that is serialized to JSON, so you have to unserialize it in this way:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data.response),
    result = response.result;
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried `JSON.parse(data)` but of course, that didn't work! your's does, so shall accept asap.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse the JSON:

```
 var data = JSON.parse(obj.response);
```